# time --format e command fails to recognize format arg?

Tags: command, time

Can someone please show me how to use `time -f "%e"` correctly? I want just the real wall clock time in seconds.

Comment: No, `time` does not deal with the real wall clock, `date` does. Try `date '+%s'`.

Comment: To time a command with [GNU time](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/), you might want `\time -f %e ...` to avoid clashing with a shell builtin.

Comment: @rowboat It WORKS, thank you guys.